# jQuery showing divs always inside viewport

Tags: jquery

I am writing a jquery web-app that basically opens a div "window" based on where you click with the mouse. You can obviously imagine that if the mouse is too much on the right or bottom of the viewport, part of the opened DIV will not be vieweable.

Is there a way, maybe in jQuery UI to have the newly shown DIV be moved a bit in the right direction of part of it in un-vieweable ( possibly when using draggable() )? If not, I will have to write my own function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Jquery UI position has flip and fit features. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as easy as using a default jqueryUI dialog!

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/GLwHN/)

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ 
        position: [e.offsetX, e.offsetY]
    });
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use jqueryui for this (modal window or something). Else you need to calculate viewport width/height, element position, -width and height and restrict positioning to viewportWidth minus elementWidth.